# What is this beanlike thing?

Tags: food-identification

I had a meal today with beanlike things I was unable to identify. They tasted something like a hard green bean, and it was about 1cm long.

[image]

Comment: Knowing what sort of restaurant you were in or what the dish you ate was might help. :)

Comment: It was in Liberty, in London, I can't remember the name of the dish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely Samphire, at least an image search for samphire gives a perfect visual match.